# Loading and accessing template variables inside text file

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

we have a bunch of text templates that are embedded resources in our visual studio solution.

I'm using a simple method like this to load them:

```
    public string getTemplate()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var templateName = "ResearchRequestTemplate.txt";
        string result;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(templateName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So I can load the file with the above method, but how do I replace the template variables inside the file with variables I've created in my code? Is that even possible? Maybe I'm going about this all wrong...

```
ResearchRequestTemplate.txt:

Hello { FellowDisplayName }

You have requested access to the { ResearchProjectTitle } Project.

    Please submit all paperwork and badge ID to { ResourceManagerDisplayName }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a series of `string.Replace()` statements.

Or you could modify the template and make use of `string.Format`:

```
Hello {0}

You have requested access to the {1} Project.

    Please submit all paperwork and badge ID to {2}
```

After you read in the template, insert the correct values:

```
return string.Format(
    result, fellowDisplayName, researchProjectTitle, resourceManagerDisplayName);
```

This could be a bit error prone if the template changes often, and someone's not being careful to make sure the numbering in the template matches the order of parameters being passed in.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 - Using Run-Time Text Templates**

---

As an elegant solution you can use [Run-time Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx). Add a new Item of Runtime Text Template to your project and and name the file `ResearchRequestTemplate.tt` put this content in it:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="FellowDisplayName" type="System.String"#>
<#@ parameter name="ResearchProjectTitle" type="System.String"#>
<#@ parameter name="ResourceManagerDisplayName" type="System.String"#>
Hello <#= FellowDisplayName #>

You have requested access to the <#= ResearchProjectTitle #> Project.

    Please submit all paperwork and badge ID to <#= ResourceManagerDisplayName #>
```

Then use it this way:

```
var template = new ResearchRequestTemplate();
template.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
template.Session["FellowDisplayName"]= value1;
template.Session["ResearchProjectTitle"]= value2;
template.Session["ResourceManagerDisplayName"] = value3;
template.Initialize();
var result = template.TransformText();
```

This is a very flexible way and you can simply extend it, because visual studio generates a C# class for your template and for example you can create a partial class for it and put some properties in it and use typed properties simply.

**Option 2 - Named String.Format**

---

You can use named string format methods:

Here is [an implementation by James Newton](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string FormatWith(this string format, object source)
    {
      return FormatWith(format, null, source);
    }

    public static string FormatWith(this string format, IFormatProvider provider, object source)
    {
      if (format == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("format");

      Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<start>\{)+(?<property>[\w\.\[\]]+)(?<format>:[^}]+)?(?<end>\})+",
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      List<object> values = new List<object>();
      string rewrittenFormat = r.Replace(format, delegate(Match m)
      {
        Group startGroup = m.Groups["start"];
        Group propertyGroup = m.Groups["property"];
        Group formatGroup = m.Groups["format"];
        Group endGroup = m.Groups["end"];

        values.Add((propertyGroup.Value == "0")
          ? source
          : DataBinder.Eval(source, propertyGroup.Value));

        return new string('{', startGroup.Captures.Count) + (values.Count - 1) + formatGroup.Value
          + new string('}', endGroup.Captures.Count);
      });

      return string.Format(provider, rewrittenFormat, values.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
"{CurrentTime} - {ProcessName}".FormatWith(
    new { CurrentTime = DateTime.Now, ProcessName = p.ProcessName });
```

You can also take a look at [an implementation by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple replacement scheme using regular expressions:

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "FellowDisplayName", "Mr Doe" },
    { "ResearchProjectTitle", "Frob the Baz" },
    { "ResourceManagerDisplayName", "Mrs Smith" },
};

string template = getTemplate();    
string result = Regex.Replace(template, "\\{\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}", m => {
    string value;
    if (replacements.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: What should happen if we don't know what the template value is?
        return string.Empty;
    }   
});
Console.WriteLine(result);
```